# Javascript won't calculate

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why my calculate button will not calculate.  It doesn't even throw any of the error messages up to the screen, but my clear button does work.  It's probably something small, but I cannot figure it out for the life of me -_-.

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
var virusRemovalPrice = 20.00;
var websiteMakingCost = 75.00;
var computerServicingCost = 100.00;

var calculateTotal = function() {
  var virusRemoval = parseFloat($("virusRemoval").value);
  var websiteMaking = parseFloat($("websiteMaking").value);
  var computerOptimizationAndSetUp = parseFloat($("computerOptimizationAndSetUp").value);
  var totalCost = parseFloat(($("totalCost").value));

  if (isNaN(virusRemoval) || virusRemoval < 0) {
    alert("Value must be numeric and at least zero. ");
    $("virusRemoval").focus()
  } else if (isNaN(websiteMaking) || websiteMaking < 0) {
    alert("Value must be numeric and at least zero. ");
    $("websiteMaking").focus()
  } else if (isNaN(computerOptimizationAndSetUp) || computerOptimizationAndSetUp < 0) {
    alert("Value must be numeric and at least zero. ");
    $("computerOptimizationAndSetUp").focus()
  } else {
    do {
      var ii = 0;
      var cost = ((virusRemovalPrice * virusRemoval) + (websiteMakingCost * websiteMaking) + (computerServicingCost * computerOptimizationAndSetUp));
      $("cost").value = cost.toFixed(2); //total cost final
      if (cost > 1) {
        alert("Your total is " + cost + " hope to see you soon!");
      }
    } while (ii = 0)


  }



};
var clearValues = function() {
  var virusRemoval = parseFloat($("virusRemoval").value = "");
  var websiteMaking = parseFloat($("websiteMaking").value = "");
  var computerOptimizationAndSetUp = parseFloat($("computerOptimizationAndSetUp").value = "");
  var totalCost = parseFloat($("totalCost").value = "");
}
```

```html
<form class="anotheremoved">
  <h2>Total Cost</h2>
  <label for="virusRemoval">Virus Removal:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="virusRemoval">
  <br />

  <label for="websiteMaking">Website Design:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="websiteMaking">
  <br />

  <label for="computerOptimizationAndSetUp">Computer Setup:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="computerOptimizationAndSetUp">
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="totalCost">Your Total Cost is:</label>
  <input type="text" id="TotalCost" disabled>
  <br />
  <input class="removed" type="button" id="calculateTotal" value="Calculate " onblur="calculateTotal()">
  <input class="removed" type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" onclick="clearValues()">
</form>
```

The reason why the loop is in there is because we were required to have a loop and I couldn't find a good reason to have one, so I used one that would always be true to get it out of the way lol.  Probably will throw an infinate loop at me or something, but I'll figure that out later, I'm just trying to get the dang on thing to do something here haha.  I've tried to rewrite this 2 other times and still get to the same spot, so I realize it's probably something small, and I am new to  Javascript.  Thank you.

Comment: Why are you redefining `$` if you're using jQuery?

Comment: Where are you using jQuery in the question?

Comment: you are redefining $. why?. Is there any particular need?

Comment: because that's how he has the assignment started out lol. I don't really know the reason, I just left it how he had default is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have `id="calculateTotal"` in the input button. Element IDs are automatically turned into top-level variables, so this is replacing the function named `calculateTotal`. Simply give the function a different name from the button's ID.

You also have a typo. The ID of the Total Cost field is `TotalCost`, but the code uses `$('totalCost')` and $('cost').

It's also better to do the calculation in `onclick`, not `onblur`. Otherwise you have to click on the button and then click on something else to see the result.

In the `clearValues` function, there's no need to assign variables and call `parseFloat`. Just set each of the values to the empty string. You could also just use `<input type="reset">`, that resets all the inputs in the form to their initial values automatically.

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
var virusRemovalPrice = 20.00;
var websiteMakingCost = 75.00;
var computerServicingCost = 100.00;

var calculateTotal = function() {
  var virusRemoval = parseFloat($("virusRemoval").value);
  var websiteMaking = parseFloat($("websiteMaking").value);
  var computerOptimizationAndSetUp = parseFloat($("computerOptimizationAndSetUp").value);
  var totalCost = parseFloat(($("TotalCost").value));

  if (isNaN(virusRemoval) || virusRemoval < 0) {
    alert("Value must be numeric and at least zero. ");
    $("virusRemoval").focus()
  } else if (isNaN(websiteMaking) || websiteMaking < 0) {
    alert("Value must be numeric and at least zero. ");
    $("websiteMaking").focus()
  } else if (isNaN(computerOptimizationAndSetUp) || computerOptimizationAndSetUp < 0) {
    alert("Value must be numeric and at least zero. ");
    $("computerOptimizationAndSetUp").focus()
  } else {
    do {
      var ii = 0;
      var cost = ((virusRemovalPrice * virusRemoval) + (websiteMakingCost * websiteMaking) + (computerServicingCost * computerOptimizationAndSetUp));
      $("TotalCost").value = cost.toFixed(2); //total cost final
      if (cost > 1) {
        alert("Your total is " + cost + " hope to see you soon!");
      }
    } while (ii = 0)
  }
};

var clearValues = function() {
  $("virusRemoval").value = "";
  $("websiteMaking").value = "";
  $("computerOptimizationAndSetUp").value = "";
  $("TotalCost").value = "";
}
```

```html
<form class="anotheremoved">
  <h2>Total Cost</h2>
  <label for="virusRemoval">Virus Removal:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="virusRemoval">
  <br />

  <label for="websiteMaking">Website Design:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="websiteMaking">
  <br />

  <label for="computerOptimizationAndSetUp">Computer Setup:</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="computerOptimizationAndSetUp">
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="totalCost">Your Total Cost is:</label>
  <input type="text" id="TotalCost" disabled>
  <br />
  <input class="removed" type="button" id="calculateTotalButton" value="Calculate " onclick="calculateTotal()">
  <input class="removed" type="button" id="clear" value="Clear" onclick="clearValues()">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That makes sense.  It's pretty bad you taught me literally more in 45 minutes than I have learned in 8 weeks of class lol.  Just to clarify and make sure I understood, the main issue is the fact that my buttonID was the same as my variable? Correct?  Outside of me having 3 variables for cost I believe?

Comment: Yes, that's why nothing was running. Didn't you see the error saying that `calculateTotal` is not a function in the Javascript console? If you then type `calculateTotal` into the console, it shows the `<input>` instead of the function.

Comment: I hope they mentioned using the Developer Tools sometime during the class.

Comment: Just Notepad ++ lol.  I now have that to look into!  Thank you again!